# Cache/Re-Use a Subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a very complex MySQL query that includes use of the same subquery three times. Will MySQL actually run the subquery three times? (It's an expensive one.) If so, is there a way for me to tell MySQL to save or cache the results so it won't do that? I could save the data in a large array then re-feed it to MySQL, but I'd rather not move it out and back into the database like that.

This is the subquery that appears three times:

```
SELECT id FROM programs 
WHERE submitter_id=32 AND id in (
    SELECT id FROM programs 
    WHERE feed_id=2478 AND id in (
        SELECT program_id FROM playlist_program_map 
        WHERE playlist_id=181)))
```

And here's an example of the full query in which the query appears:

```
SELECT object_id, programs.created AS created, 
MATCH(text) AGAINST ('excellent ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM comments_programs USE INDEX (text) 
LEFT JOIN programs ON programs.id=object_id 
WHERE object_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM programs 
    WHERE 1 AND id IN (
        SELECT id FROM programs 
        WHERE submitter_id=32 AND id in (
            SELECT id FROM programs 
            WHERE feed_id=2478 AND id in (
                SELECT program_id FROM playlist_program_map 
                WHERE playlist_id=181)))) 
AND MATCH(text) AGAINST ('excellent ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0)

UNION (

SELECT object_id, programs.created AS created, 
MATCH(text) AGAINST ('excellent ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM descriptions_programs USE INDEX (text) 
LEFT JOIN programs ON programs.id=object_id 
WHERE object_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM programs 
    WHERE 1 AND id IN (
        SELECT id FROM programs 
        WHERE submitter_id=32 AND id in (
            SELECT id FROM programs 
            WHERE feed_id=2478 AND id in (
                SELECT program_id FROM playlist_program_map 
                WHERE playlist_id=181)))) 
AND MATCH(text) AGAINST ('excellent ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 AND current=1 ) 

UNION (

SELECT object_id, programs.created AS created, 
MATCH(text) AGAINST ('excellent ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM titles_programs USE INDEX (text) 
LEFT JOIN programs ON programs.id=object_id 
WHERE object_id IN (
    SELECT id FROM programs 
    WHERE 1 AND id IN (
        SELECT id FROM programs 
        WHERE submitter_id=32 AND id in (
            SELECT id FROM programs 
            WHERE feed_id=2478 AND id in (
                SELECT program_id FROM playlist_program_map 
                WHERE playlist_id=181)))) 
AND MATCH(text) AGAINST ('excellent ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)>0 AND current=1;
```

Comment: I've pasted an example into the original question. Hey, you asked. :-)

Comment: It's a UNION of three SELECTs with LEFT JOINs. The WHERE clause of each includes an IN (<subquery>) where <subquery> is the same in every instance. The subquery is a filter that drastically reduces the size of the dataset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See what `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` says.

If it says `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY` or `UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY`, then it will be reevaluated each time it's used.

This happens if the subquery uses session variables or is a correlated subquery.

If it doesn't, it most probably will be cached.

If your case the subquery will not be cached, it will be reevaluated in each `UNION`'ed set.

You subquery, though, seems to be too complicated. Why don't you just use:

```
SELECT id
FROM   playlist_program_map ppm, programs p
WHERE  ppm.playlist_id = 181
       AND p.id = ppm.program_id
       AND submitter_id = 32
       AND feed_id = 2478
```

If you have an index on `playlist_program_map (playlist_id)`, this query should work like a charm.

Could you please tell me two more things:

1. How many rows are there in `playlist_program_map` and how many `DISTINCT playlist_id` values are there?

   - How many rows are there in `programs` and how many `DISTINCT submitter_id, feed_id` pairs are there?

From your comment I can conclude that there are **10** `programs` per `playlist` in average, and **200** `programs` per `(submitter, feed)` pair. This means your index on `playlist_program_map` is more selective than the one on `(submitter, feed)`, and `playlist_program_map` must be leading in the join.

The fulltext index in your case also doesn't seem to be very selective, given that you need to join **10** programs out of **2,000,000**.

You may better try the following:

```
SELECT object_id, programs.created AS created
FROM   playlist_program_map ppm, programs p, comments_programs cp
WHERE  ppm.playlist_id = 181
       AND p.id = ppm.program_id
       AND p.submitter_id = 32
       AND p.feed_id = 2478
       AND cp.object_id = p.id
       AND cp.text REGEXP 'excellent'
```

, and repeat this for all three tables.

Comment: All the subqueries are reported as DEPENDENT SUBQUERY.

Comment: 0. Yes, there's a playlist_id index.
1. p_p_m will have ~500,000 rows. ~50,000 DISTINCT playlist_id values.
2. programs will have ~2,000,000 rows. ~10,000 DISTINCT submitter_id, feed_id

Comment: The real-word queries must use MySQL's FULLTEXT mechanism. The match for 'excellent' is just a trivial example for the sake of brevity. This whole thing is a FULLTEXT search of three tables.

Comment: Yes, but FULLTEXT mechanism and FULLTEXT index are different things. MATCH … IN BOOLEAN MODE works without using a FULLTEXT index (and without even having one). You may try to get rid of USE INDEX (text) and see if using an index on OBJECT_ID will speed up the query (which it most probably will)

Comment: This has been extremely helpful. The actual case is even more complex since I have to build the queries dynamically in PHP. Your tips have drastically reduced the query execution times. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, mysql IN clauses with a sub-select run very slow.  Better to use join.  Your sub-query becomes:

SELECT id from programs P1 INNER JOIN programs P2 ON P1.id = P2.id INNER JOIN playlist_program_map PMAP ON P2.id = PMAP.program_id WHERE P1.submitter_id=32 AND P2.feed_id=2478 AND PMAP.playlist_id=181

It will run much faster.