# UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please tell me what is `UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY` in MySQL?

How it is different from `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`?

By what criteria does MySQL consider a subquery an `UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY`?

Comment: What's the query in question?

Answer (score 0):

Relevant: [Cache/Re-Use a Subquery in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658937/cache-re-use-a-subquery-in-mysql) which is also the first result on Google if you had done some research.

Shows if a query uses session variables or is a correlated subquery.  A correlated subquery is a subquery that relies on variables from the primary query and can not be run independently.  (So if you can't run the subquery separately, then it is correlated)